# Propagating Blame in Team City

Tags: teamcity

In Team City we have the facility to send out an email when a developer breaks the build.

However, our build has got more complex now, so we have three separate stages joined together in a pipeline:

BUILD

DEPLOY

TEST

The TEST stage is an integration test, running in a development environment.

The problem is that when a developer commits code, the builds for the first two stages may complete, but the third breaks.  The developer doesn't get an email to say that this has caused the problem though.

Any ideas on how best to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set up your build chain correctly for this to work.

Deploy should have a Snapshot Dependency on Build.
On the VCS Settings of Deploy, the "Show changes from snapshot dependencies" checkbox should be ticked.

Similarly, Test should have a Snapshot Dependency on Deploy. (Not Build)
And again, on the VCS Settings of Test, the "Show changes from snapshot dependencies" checkbox should be ticked.

A final check would be to navigate to the Build Chains page of the project, and it should show a clean serial build chain like Build -> Deploy -> Test.

Answer (score 0):

1. Do you checkout the same code for testing in your test step, or is it just a remote run feature that does not need to check out any code . In case you (1) do not need to check out code or (2) if you are checking out  the same code in Test as in build , you can setup snapshot dependencies among the builds . You can even checkout the code in your Test step and do nothing with the checked out code. This way if your build fails, you can still figure out whoose check-in broke the build . Remember that setting up a snapshot dependency is an important part of this
2. In case your 3 targets are stable (i.e they do not fail and do not need to be rerun) , You can also try to convert the 3 targets into one target of 3 sub steps . That way you always know whose check-in failed the test builds